# Exclude random entry from another entry tag

Tags: channel-entries, random

I'm trying to load a random channel entry on page landing, while excluding that entry from the navigation to view more in the sidebar.... Here's what i want to do, but I'm not sure how to make this work...

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="success_story"
  dynamic="no"
  orderby="random"
  limit="1"
}
{content}
{/exp:channel:entries}

<ul>
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="success_story"
  entry_id="not (entry_id from above)"
}
<li>{title}</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an embed.

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="success_story"
  orderby="random"
  dynamic="no"
  limit="1"
}
{content}
{embed="group/embed" eid="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}


<!-- Then create the group/embed template (call it whatever you want) and put this -->
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="success_story"
  entry_id="not {embed:eid}"
  orderby="random"
}
<li>{title}</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

You could use Stash too, but maybe for another day. :)

Comment: simple and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Stash way:

Stash the channel entries. The order doesn't matter.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="entries" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="success_story"}
    {stash:id}{entry_id}{/stash:id}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:content}{content}{/stash:content}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Output one entry randomly and stash the ID.
Use `parse_tags="yes"` to be able to nest an `{exp:stash:set}`.

```
{exp:stash:get_list 
  name="entries"
  orderby="random"
  limit="1"
  parse_tags="yes"
}
  {content}
  {exp:stash:set name="random_entry_id"}{id}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Output everything *except* the random entry.
You can control the order here using the `orderby` param.

```
<ul>
{exp:stash:get_list
  name="entries"
  orderby="date"
  match="#^(?!{exp:stash:random_entry_id}$).*$#"
  against="id"
  parse="inward"
}
  <li>{title}</li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</ul>
```